# JQuery POST failing with HTTPS on the same server

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, post

I have a strange issue with JQuery 1.6.2 and POSTing to a page on the same server.

Error:

```
POST https://[phpfile].php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
send jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
f.extend.ajax jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
f.(anonymous function) jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
populateList main.js:1112
(anonymous function) main.js:211
e.resolveWith jquery-1.6.2.min.js:16
w jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
send.d
```

Situation:

This is a Facebook app that will do the common things (note, every release before yesterday was ok, and nothing changed code wise in regards to the files affected).  When the app loads it will request a list of friends and gifts based on the user.

At first JQuery was causing bugs when linking directly to Google's api page, so the JQuery file was moved to a local folder.  Now when we try to use POST, anywhere in the code, we get this error.

**Can someone shed some light please.**

Note: Because the error was a 500, I at first thought there may be a problem with the php script.  So the script was verified to be in tact and we did sample POST messages to the script directly **WITHOUT** failing.

Comment: The error is happening on the PHP side, there's no question there. It may be a logic problem in your javascript that is not sending the expected parameters to your php, but we can't help with that without seeing code.

Comment: @KevinB noted I will provide a sample of the code shortly.  The error is actually not on the PHP page.  I assumed that in the beginning because of the 500 error but the page was fine - I made a simple post to the page to test.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX requests are subject to several rules that are intended to aid security.

To make an AJAX request to your `https` page, the page the AJAX is on must also be served via `https`.

The protocol (http/https) and domain (including sub domain) must be the same for a standard AJAX request.

Comment: This is also my assumption.  Both the .js and .php files are on the same server with same protocol, although Facebook will only switch to https if the user's settings allows.  That was also tested but even when Facebook security settings were set to https (so both Facebook and server are on the same protocol) it still failed.  I will provide a sample soon.